# Time Efficient Method of Asymmetric Laplace MLE of Location Parameter

Tags: maximum-likelihood, fitting, laplace-approximation

Reviewing "[Tests of fit for the asymmetric Laplace distribution](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/sii/2014/0007/0003/SII-2014-0007-0003-a010.pdf)" under "Maximum Likelihood Estimation", the proposed method of determining the $\hat{\theta}$ seems problematic from a processing time perspective. Without any shortcuts - assuming an approximately mean-zero distribution with a static set of size $N$, it would take approximately $N(N/2)$ iterations every time new data comes in on a sliding time series window.

What sort of shortcuts can I take in order to minimize the number of iterations on the dataset to locate $x_r$? I already have some empirical statistics like mean, median, the four standardized and unstandardized central moments, quartiles, a sorted set, etc.